# How can I compare a file's SHA256 hash in PowerShell to a known value?

Tags: powershell, hash, sha

If I've downloaded a file with a known SHA256 hash, how can I use PowerShell to check that the file matches the expected hash?

Answer (score 40):

The `Get-FileHash` cmdlet computes hashes for files, and [SHA256 is its default hash algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7).

To compute the hash of a file:

```
Get-FileHash .\path\to\foo.zip
```

This produces something like:

```
Algorithm       Hash                                                                   Path
---------       ----                                                                   ----
SHA256          15DC0502666851226F1D9C0FE352CCAF0FFDEFF2350B6D2D08A90FCD1F610A10       C:\Users\me\path\to\foo.zip
```

To compare to the known value, extract the computed hash value alone from the output of Get-FileHash, then compare it to the expected value as a (quoted) string literal. Conveniently this comparison appears to be case-insensitive

```
(Get-FileHash .\path\to\foo.zip).Hash -eq "15dc0502666851226f1d9c0fe352ccaf0ffdeff2350b6d2d08a90fcd1f610a10"
```

```
True
```

...or if you've got the expected hash in a file, say `expected-hash.sha256`

```
(Get-FileHash '.\path\to\foo.zip').Hash -eq (Get-Content .\expected-hash.sha256)
```

```
True
```

Comment: Why do you ask a question when you actually already know the answer? You may start a blog if you want to share your thoughts with the world. ;-)

Comment: @Olaf ...because it's [encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)?

Comment: OK.   ... learned something today. Thanks for that. ;-)  .... now I'm curious ... how long did it take you to find the solution?

Comment: not terribly long, but I did have synthesize some information from a few sources to get a working one-liner, which I thought was worthwhile to share.

Comment: "Conveniently this comparison appears to be case-insensitive" - Yes, "-eq" performs a case-insensitive comparison. If you ever want case-sensitive comparisons for things you can use "-ceq"

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path <path/to/hash-file>) -DifferenceObject (Get-FileHash <path/to/test-file> -Algorithm SHA512).Hash.ToLower()
```

Where *<path/to/hash-file>* should be replaced with the path to a file containing the expected hash and *<path/to/test-file>* should be replaced with the file to test the hash against.