# How can I compare a files's SHA256 hash in powershell to a known value? Additional question

Tags: powershell, hash, compare

@Mac I just found the below link for powershell, and it is very helpful. How would one specify that there is normal text inside, say a .txt file other than just the hash. For example the .txt I'm working with has descriptive text in it, the first line is the filename, second line is MD5 Checksum: xxxxxxxxxxxx, third line is SHA-1 Checksum: xxxxxxxxx, and the last line is SHA-256 checksum: xxxxxxxxx. Any ideas?

[How can I compare a files's SHA256 hash in powershell to a known value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63396620/how-can-i-compare-a-filess-sha256-hash-in-powershell-to-a-known-value)

Comment: This is the powershell code that my question refers to. (Get-FileHash '.\path\to\foo.zip').Hash -eq (Get-Content .\expected-hash.sha256)

Comment: I'm not following, the hashes are hard coded in the contents of the file? If so, please provide a representation of the file content.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Select-Object -Last 1` to grab only the last line output by `Get-Content`:

```
# Grab last line from file
$sha256Line = Get-Content .\file-with-hashes.txt |Select -Last 1

# Remove everything but the trailing hash
$expectedHash = $sha256Line -replace '^.*([A-F0-9]{64})\s*$','$1'
```

Now you can compare the `Hash` output from `Get-FileHash` to `$expectedHash`

Comment: ...or `Get-Content file.txt -Tail 1` :)

Comment: Excellent!!! Thank you both so much for your help! I now have a great automation!